# is form in if else affect document ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i have form where this form generated by if else, and I use this form id to trigger one javascript to validate text box (if textboxt empty then alert & disable button submit), i tried to alert with "cok" character it works, but the function is not

this is my form

```
if($total == 0){
echo '
<tr>
   <td colspan="5" align="center">Ups, Keranjang kosong!</td>
</tr>
</table>';
echo '
<p>
<div align="right">
   <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">&laquo; Continue Shopping</a>
</div>
</p>';
} else {
echo '
<form id="formku" action="prosescheckout.php" method="post">
   <tr style="background-color: #DDD;">
      <tdcolspan="1" ></td><b>Subtotal </b>
      <td><b>: Rp.</b></td>
      <td name="totbarang" id="totbarang"><b>'.($total).'</b></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="background-color: #DDD;">
      <tdcolspan="1"></td>
      <td>
         <b>Total Barang  </b>
      </td>
      <td><b>:</b></td>
      <td name="berat" id="berat"><b>'.($totalberat).'</b></td>
   </tr>
   </table>';
   }
   ?>
   </table>
   </div>
   </div>
   <hr class="divider">
   <div align="center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#detharga" >
      <a class="menu_links" style="cursor: pointer;">
      Lihat detail transaksi ▼
      </a>
   </div>
   </hr>
   <div class="hero-unit">Harap isi rincian pengiriman barang dibawah ini !</div>
   <table class="table table-condensed">
      <!--<input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php/* echo abs((int)$_GET['total']);*/ ?>">-->
      <tr>
         <td><label for="nm_usr">Nama</label></td>
         <td><input name="nm_usr" type="text" value="<?php echo $datauser["nm_usr"]; ?>" class="required" minlength="6" id="nm_usr" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Masukkan nama lengkap anda" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label for="almt_usr">Alamat</label></td>
         <td><textarea name="almt_usr" type="text" value="" class="required" id="almt_usr" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Alamat tujuan pengiriman barang pesanan Anda"/><?php echo $datauser["almt_usr"]; ?></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label for="Provinsi">Provinsi</label></td>
         <td>
            <select name="desprovince" id="desprovince" >
               <option>Provinsi</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label for="Kota" >Kota</label></td>
         <td>
            <select onchange="showService();Kurir();" name="descity" id="descity">
               <option></option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td><input type="submit" value="Simpan Data" name="submit"  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"/>&nbsp;<a href="prosescheckout.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Kembali</a></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

and here's my js

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script def src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formku").validate();
    });
    alert ("cok");
</script> 
<style type="text/css">
    label.error {
        color: red;
        padding-left: .5em;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger: "focus"});   
});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a form validation right after the page has just been loaded?

Comment: @Teemu: There's never enough jquery :)

Comment: @teemu yep form id = formku succeed triggered, i tried to windows alert it, and work, just function not working

Comment: Why don't you create correct values with PHP already? I suppose you want to validate the form after user has filled it? Use `onsubmit` event to call the validation instead of `.ready`.

Comment: @teemu yeah I can work with that way too, but i need it to validate when at state focus on textbox, so some function will trigger some output text, I solved this just now, the problem is header form must not in if else, so i put outside if else then pass some variable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form header must not in if else state, so document ready can triggered some function, and pass some variable inside it via jquery..